# Smart card reader not able to detect in remote host

Tags: windows, remote-desktop-services, smartcard

I have a situation where Host A (USB smart card reader connected) trying to RDP'ed to Host B, however, Host B was not able to detect the smart card reader on Host A in the remote session.

Thing I have tried:

1. Directly connect the USB smart card reader on Host B. Host B able
   to detect the reader. I have also confirmed that the smart card able
   to detect on host A when connected directly.
2. When specifying IP in mstsc.exe, smart card option was checked under Local devices and resources on Host A. But Host B still unable to detect the reader on Host A.
3. In Host A and B group policy, I have confirmed that every policy in Computer Configuration >Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Device and Resource Redirection were "Not Configured".
4. I got another machine, Host C. So I tried from Host A RDP'ed onto Host C, the smart card on Host A can be detected on Host C.

**Host B Specification**

*Edition: Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC*

*Version: 1809*

*Build: 17763.2183*

What I wanted to achieve is Host B able to detect the smart card reader connected to Host A during the remote session from Host A to Host B.

I have spent quite sometime for this issue but still not able to find out what is the issue.
Anyone can shed some lights regarding this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved the problem yet, maybe I can help you!

I recently read an article, in this situation you need to look at the Windows logs on Host Y after the RDP connection has been established. There should be error messages or warnings that point you toward the problem so it can be addressed.
See also the article [emv smart card reader](https://www.flexihub.com/access-remote-emv-smart-cardreader.html) for other possibilities of problems and solutions.

Hope I was able to help you!